# ES6 Class Object Inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When I use `console.log()` I get the context of my canvas.

But, when I use in my Rectangle class `moveTo(10,10)`; I get `ctx is undefined`.

How can I get this to work?

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.draw(ctx);
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }
}

class BaseShape extends Shape {
  constructor(color) {
    super();
    this.color = color;
  }
}

class Rectangle extends BaseShape {
  constructor(color) {
    super(color);
  }
}

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var x = c.getContext("2d");

var rec = new Rectangle("green");
rec.draw(x);
console.log(rec);
```

Rectangle class

```
class Rectangle extends BaseShape {
  constructor(color) {
    super(color);
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you swapped the draw and constructor. should probably set the context in the constructor and then do the draw in the draw method... once the context is set in the constructor it doesn't need to be passed to the draw method.

Comment: Your `Recangle` class has neither `moveTo` nor `draw` methods? Please show us your whole code.

Comment: this is my code, i will later add a extra class Circle that's why i want extend from Shape

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of the `Rectangle` class (`new Rectangle("green")`), the `Rectangle` constructor calls the `BaseShape` constructor, which calls the `Shape` constructor *with no arguments* (so `ctx` becomes `undefined`), which calls the `Rectangle.prototype.draw()` method. Since `ctx` is `undefined`, you get an error.

Comment: ye, but when i console.log of my rectangle i get my canvas. Idk how i can draw my rectangle with extending from the 2 upper Classes

Comment: @olalalaa1599 `console.log(rec)` should log `undefined`, because `new Rectangle("green")` throws an error. I think that you didn't show all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not save the context to the object. I would pass it into the `draw` method. Java's `JComponent.paintComponent` method takes a `Graphics` parameter.

So, in JavaScript, you should pass your `CanvasRenderingContext2D` into your draw method.

I have provided example shapes such as squares and triangles, below.

```js
class AbstractShape {
  constructor(origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
  }
}

class DrawableShape extends AbstractShape {
  constructor(origin, color, fill) {
    super(origin);
    this.color = color || '#000';
    this.fill = fill || '#FFF';
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    this.onRedraw(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

class Rectangle extends DrawableShape {
  constructor(origin, width, height, color, fill) {
    super(origin, color, fill);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
  onRedraw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.origin.x, this.origin.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x + this.width, this.origin.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x + this.width, this.origin.y + this.height);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x, this.origin.y + this.height);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x, this.origin.y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
  constructor(origin, size, color, fill) {
    super(origin, size, size, color, fill);
  }
}

class Triangle extends DrawableShape {
  constructor(origin, width, height, color, fill) {
    super(origin, color, fill);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
  onRedraw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.origin.x + this.width / 2, this.origin.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x + this.width, this.origin.y + this.height);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x, this.origin.y + this.height);
    ctx.lineTo(this.origin.x + this.width / 2, this.origin.y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

class EquilateralTriangle extends Triangle {
  constructor(origin, size, color, fill) {
    super(origin, size * 1.1339741, size, color, fill);
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('draw').getContext('2d');
var rec = new Rectangle({ x : 10, y : 10 }, 60, 100, '#F00', '#0FF');
var tri = new EquilateralTriangle({ x : 100, y : 10 }, 100, '#00F', '#FF0');
var sqa = new Square({ x : 240, y : 10 }, 100);

rec.draw(ctx);
tri.draw(ctx);
sqa.draw(ctx);
```

```html
<canvas id="draw" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```